# Query adds name behind data

Tags: sql-server

I'm running a query that looks like this.

```html
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteImage]
    @AdvID INT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE a 
    SET a.Status = 0
    FROM Advertisement a
    WHERE a.AdvID = @AdvID
END
```

It sets the status to 0, but I also want to make the query add a word to the "Name" column which is (Deleted) so that when I want to run another query, I can do something like

```
IF a.Name LIKE "Deleted"  
   SET a.STATUS = 0
ELSE IF a.startDate <= GETDATE() 
   SET a.STATUS = 1
```

Please help thank you!!

```html
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteImage]
    @AdvID INT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE a 
    SET a.Status = 0, a.Name = Name + "Deleted"
    FROM Advertisement a
    WHERE a.AdvID = @AdvID
END
```

Which is something I assume like this but I know it's the wrong format

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here?

Comment: Why to tag `c#` and `asp.net`?

Comment: Is there a query that i can use to add words behind the Name? for example the name of the image is Testing123. But when i execute the query, it becomes Testing123[Deleted]

Comment: Don't do this. It's poor practice to mark a field that way with data that's not really part of the field.

Comment: Don't use double quotes as a string delimiter in tsql. That is a bad practice and requires special settings to work as you intend. In addition, your second code snippet is not valid tsql. You will struggle if you confuse the syntax and coding environments you intend to use. And I agree with Joel - don't do this. You can create a computed column that will append "deleted" to the name if there is a real need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query.

Here I have used `CONCAT` instead of `+`.

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[DeleteImage]
    @AdvID int
    AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE a SET a.Status = 0 , a.Name = CONCAT(Name,'+','Deleted')
        FROM Advertisement a
        WHERE a.AdvID = @AdvID
    END
```

Use below query for the condition if `Name like '%Deleted%'` then Status=0 or else if `startDate<=GETDATE()` then Status=1.

```
UPDATE a SET a.Status = 
        CASE WHEN a.Name LIKE '%Deleted%' THEN 0  
             WHEN a.startDate <= GETDATE() THEN 1 
             ELSE a.Status END
        FROM Advertisement a
        WHERE a.AdvID = @AdvID
```